# Que hace la funcion gotoXY en C

Tags: c

- Buenas, hace poco estaba haciendo un programa de impresion grafica de arboles binarios por terminal y necesite una funcion tipo gotoXY, me encontre una implementacion algo peculiar que contiene caracteres que nunca habia visto ...

```
    void gotoXY(int x, int y)
    {
        printf("%c[%d;%df", 0x1B, y, x);
    }
```

- ***Alguien sabe que esta haciendo esta funcion especificamente? que significan todos estos caracteres ?***

Comment: El 0x1B es el valor de `ESC` en código ASCII. Los otros dos valores que se imprimen son los parámetros que se pasan (`x` e `y`).

Comment: Busca en internet sobre los codigos de escape ansi.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que dijo Londo

> "El 0x1B es el valor de ESC en código ASCII. Los otros dos valores que
> se imprimen son los parámetros que se pasan (x e y)."z

es correcto, pero el propósito de la llamada es para enviar un comando ANSI al console para mover el cursor a la ubicación (x,y).  Puede leer de códigos ANSI aquí https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI

Comment: Mencioná en tu respuesta el contenido del comentario al que hacés referencia. Puede que ese comentario más adelante se elimine, convirtiendo a tu respuesta en incompleta.